# ExtJS EditorGridPanel ~ set row height and cell width to display all cell content

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3, gridpanel

When cells in an ExtJS GridPanel or EditorGridPanel contain more data than they can display, users have to resize columns.

Is there a way to have the GridPanel automatically expand the width and height of its columns/rows to display its data? Are there any examples out there of doing this?

Using ExtJS 3.4

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The autofit isn´t implemented until version 4.0.2, but you can use **with** and **minWidth** properties.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-method-autoSize

```
columns: [
    { text: 'data1', dataIndex: 'name',  width: 150, autoSizeColumn: true },
    { text: 'data2', dataIndex: 'email', width: 100, autoSizeColumn: true, minWidth: 150 },
    { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone', width: 50 }
]
```